# Virtualbox USB Support

Tags: 14.04, usb, virtualbox

Thanks for the tutorials to activate USB support but

-Enable Usb Controller- Stays greyed-out and refuses to work.

I have Installed the VM VirtualBox from Oracle 
I have Installed Extension Pack for my version 5.0.8
I have run the commands
sudo usermod -aG vboxusers user

I have checked in Users and groups that vboxusers is present and that I have a group id

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and have installed windows 7 on the virtual machine
USB devices do show up in Virtualbox , and when Clicked to connect to Virtual Windows System, the Virtual Windows makes a Noise as if something is there but nothing happens.

Please help, this is very frustrating, Thank you very much.

Comment: Just to make sure - since you did not mention it - you have installed the Guest Additions in the Guest OS as well? That is required.

Answer (score 0):

Download **Extension Pack** in Extension https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

after open **virtualbox** **> File > Preferences > Extensions** and install the file and try.